# Insert multiple attribute as foreign key

Tags: sql, database-design, foreign-keys

I have 2 tables: `Lecturer` and `Department`.

The `Lecturer` table has these columns:

```
id, email, phone, expertise, dept_id.
```

The `Department` table has these:

```
dept_id, dept_name, dept_code, dept_program.
```

Sample data is as follows:

**Lecturer** table

```
(id=1, email= a@a.com, phone= 9999, expertise= multimedia and programming, dept_id=1)
```

**Department** table

```
(id=1, dept_name=Computer Science, dept_code=CS, dept_program=Bachelor of Comp Science)
```

The expertise column has several values, and some lecturers might have more than 5 expertise areas, so I think I should create another table for expertise alone.  But how to insert multiple attributes of expertise into lecturer table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't really do this by changing only the `lecturer` table. Normally, you handle multivalued attributes by creating seperate tables. In this case, you would create one table to hold expertise attributes and another one to associate expertises with lecturers. As a bonus, that'll also help to prevent inconsistencies when it comes to descriptions of expertise.

The resulting tables might look like this:

```
department(dept_id, dept_name, dept_code, dept_program)
lecturer(id, email, phone, dept_id*)
expertise(id, description)
lecturer_expertise(lect_id*, expertise_id*)
```

Comment: The lecturer table does need one change in this design - remove the expertise field

Comment: Right, I missed that. I've edited the answer to reflect that.

Comment: And while you're at it, a lecturer may also have multiple email addresses and multiple phone numbers which can lead you to a few more mapping tables... :)

Comment: I created the tables but how can i show the department name for the dept_id in lecturer? should i use inner join?

Comment: That's what joins are for.
`SELECT lecturer.id, department.dept_name
 FROM lecturer, department
 WHERE lecturer.dept_id = department.dept_id;`